# Where/how does Jupyter notebook hook into python's repr/str

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[In jupyter notebook: python3 kernel]

If I make a data-frame in pandas or a matrix in sympy it prints very nicely
ie it looks quite like a spreadsheet/matrix etc

How does it do it?
Who does it?

The data-frame does not seem to have anything special (eg generating html) in the str/repr methods.
Tried in ordinary python and jupyter. Jupyter's printing is much more sophisticated.

So where how does it hook in?

Comment: Pandas dataframes do implement both __str__() and __repr__().

Comment: Clarified question based on @MaxPowers comment

Comment: @Rusi - try also making the question title more descriptive of the actual question.

Comment: @josh Changed as asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only speak for pandas but I imagine sympy works in a similar way.

Pandas converts a `DataFrame` into an HTML string. If we print this string it it looks even worse than a when we just print a DataFrame.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(5)})

print(data._repr_html_())

'<div>\n<style scoped>\n    .dataframe tbody tr....'
```

If instead we use Jupyter's `HTML` to display this, Jupyter knows to render this in the web browser as HTML and thus is is displayed as an HTML table.

```
HTML(data._repr_html_())

    col
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

Comment: Thanks @josh
On python mailing list got some more details
https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/integrating.html
Seems important to note that web-searching for jupyter sometimes needs to be changed to searching for ipython

Comment: Just found some more data here
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jupyter/98dyewlAyDM/discussion