# How does an Object of a class get printed in the Python REPL or Jupyter Notebook when it is entered and run without any parenthesis

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, read-eval-print-loop

Background: I am working with the SymPy Module in jupyter notebooks. I want to create a sub/child class of the Matrix class of sympy (which is actually sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix).

I write this =>

```
import sympy as sym
class Mat(sym.Matrix):
  def __init__(self,a):
    self.a = super(a)
```

Then I call the following in a seperate cell

```
X=Mat([[1,2,3]])
```

This give an error

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-9d0dfad5081f> in <module>
----> 1 X= Mat([[1,2,3]])

<ipython-input-153-41d7b2cc4dd1> in __init__(self, a)
      1 class Mat(sym.Matrix):
      2     def __init__(self,a):
----> 3         self.a = super(a)

TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not list
```

Not knowing the cause of this I tried this

```
class Mat:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = sym.Matrix(a)
```

then the assignment passed.

Now I ran this in the Next Cell alone (Let's say this is like just executing the **Name** for simplicity)

```
X
```

and got the output

```
<__main__.Mat at 0x7f80b77f8b80>
```

but I was expecting

```
[1 2 3]
```

or

```
Matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
```

These are the outputs that come in Jupyter Notebook and Python REPL respectively when I create a regular sym.Matrix object and just execute it's **Name**

Note: I know the existence of `__str__` and `__repr__` but those are helpful only if I use `print(X)`

Note: I tried definining `__call__` as

```
def __call__(self):
  return self.a
```

but it works only if I first execute `X=X()` then execute `X`

So My Question is, what is that internal method (maybe a magic method) that is called when executing just the Object **Name** and How do I define it for my class, if in future I create a class without inheritance (so I don't have to fallback on the super class method for the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking [at the doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#module-IPython.display) we have:

> In Python, objects can declare their textual representation using the
> _*repr*_ method. IPython expands on this idea and allows objects to declare other, rich representations including:
>
> _repr_html_: return raw HTML as a string, or a tuple (see below).
>
> _repr_json_: return a JSONable dict, or a tuple (see below).
>
> _repr_jpeg_: return raw JPEG data, or a tuple (see below).
>
> _repr_png_: return raw PNG data, or a tuple (see below).
>
> _repr_svg_: return raw SVG data as a string, or a tuple (see below).
>
> _repr_latex_: return LaTeX commands in a string surrounded by “$”, or a tuple (see below).
>
> _repr_mimebundle_: return a full mimebundle containing the mapping

As an addition [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202162/where-how-does-jupyter-notebook-hook-into-pythons-repr-str) seems to be related.

A working snippet should be something like:

```
import sympy as sym
class Mat(sym.Matrix):
  def __init__(self,a):
    self.a = sym.Matrix(a)
  def _repr_html_(self):
        return f"<p><h1>{self.a.__repr__()}</h1></p>"
```

Which results in a similar output:
[image]

Comment: This suggestion works, Could you please also tell me why did I get the first error? according to SymPy docs, we create a Matrix Object using Matrix(arg). so isn't my inheritance correct?

Comment: Found the Fix for the first Error, thanks to you it led me to the another solution

`class Mat(sym.Matrix):
    def __init__(self,a):
       self = sym.Matrix(a)`

Takes care of the first error

Comment: Sorry, I was away. I'm happy you solved it!